# Hibernate: Should I include the 'version' field to hashcode() and equals() methods

Tags: hibernate, version, hashcode, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I know that when overriding `hashcode()` and `equals()` of my persistent entities I should not include ID and only include the meaningful properties that uniquely identify the object.
But what about `version` field which is used for the *optimistic concurrency control* by Hibernate? Should I skip it as well, just like ID? What if let's say `new User(name='John', version=1).equals(new User(name='John',version=2))`, won't it confuse Hibernate OCC anyhow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is recommended that you implement equals() and hashCode() using Business key equality. Business key equality means that the equals() method compares only the properties that form the business key. It is a key that would identify our instance in the real world (a natural candidate key)

So you should **not** include version property in the `equals()` `hashcode()`

Refer: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Comment: Yeah, I've read that. But since the `version` field is not mentioned there and taking into account the purpose of it (different values mean different objects) I doubted. But Hibernate recommends not to use `version` for anything else in the application. So, the more I think about it the more I get convinced that the `version` should **not** be included in `equals()` and `hashcode()`.